# Capture pid when starting a background process in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to capture the pid of a background process run in bash.

I tried

```
somecommand & > somecommand.pid
```

It outputs the pid to the screen but it's not part of stdout of the command.

```
[1] 1778
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The special variable `$!` contains the PID of the most recent job placed in the background:

```
$ sleep 4 &
$ sleep_pid=$!
$ echo $sleep_pid
4456
```

This is documented in [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) of `man bash`